# When I use my own admob id, ad loads usually failed. (with test_id ad loads very well),

Tags: android, admob, ads

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                println(TAG+" banner onAdClosed");
                super.onAdClosed();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                println(TAG+" banner onAdFailedToLoad");

                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                mAdView.loadAd(mAdRequest);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                println(TAG+" banner onAdLeftApplication");
                super.onAdLeftApplication();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                println(TAG+" banner onAdOpened");
                super.onAdOpened();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {

                println(TAG+" banner onAdLoaded");
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }
        });
```

When I use the test_id from admob. 
The ad loads very well (2-3sec the ad will show up successfully)

But when I use my own admob id.
I get this from logcat:

```
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdFailedToLoad
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdFailedToLoad
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdFailedToLoad
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdFailedToLoad
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdFailedToLoad
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdFailedToLoad

.........................
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdFailedToLoad
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdFailedToLoad
I/System.out: MainActivity banner onAdLoaded
```

And by when the ad will be loaded, is not determined.
Its my first time to use admob.

sometimes i can also get the error:

```
W/WebKit: A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
W/Ads: JS: A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
```

---

I have captured the error code from the callback function "onAdFailedToLoad",

The error code is ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL, this means "The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory."

according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/ad-events

My AdRequest:

```
mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
                build();
```

Comment: Do not load another ad in `onAdFailedToLoad`. You're gonna be stuck in a loop when there is no ad inventory or if the user doesn't have an internet connection. Where are you creating `mAdRequest`?

Comment: Hallo,,,mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
                build();

Answer (score 0):

Check your adSize

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```